# Primary Key Conflict on Tenth Record

Tags: .net-core

I'm using .netcore entityframework. My primary key is of integer type and auto generated which works fine until the tenth record which then starts conflicting with the second record

Comment: That sounds quite impossible. You should provide some example code if you need any help...

Comment: Yeah, so I thought too. but thats what I'm seeing. the first nine entries are successfully added to the table, then the tenth starts generating a primary key conflict error

Comment: We can not help if you do not share the code you use. Your question is very general and abstract.

Comment: Could you add some code and details of the type of DB you use?

Comment: Ok, so I did some trial and error and this is what I got. After running the "Add-Migration" command I edited the resulting migration class and changed the "incrementBy " defaut value from 10 to 1 (Thought I was being smart) before running the "Update-Database" command. Well, I Went back deleted the entire migration folder, removed the database  from SQL server. I run the migration again, left everything at the default and the problem disappeared.